# Setting soft limit above hard does not fail in terms of exit code?

Tags: security, limit, ulimit

```
root@Andromeda:/# ulimit -n -S
2048
root@Andromeda:/# ulimit -n -H
2048
root@Andromeda:/# ulimit -n -S 4096
2048
root@Andromeda:/# echo $?
0
```

Failure to set soft limit above the hard one makes sense.

What perhaps does not make sense is why the exit code of this attempt is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that putting `-H` or `-S` at the end causes it to report, not set. And therefore no error. The number at the end seems to be ignored. As far as I can tell this should be a usage error, but not a limits error.

Comment: thanks; and what is the syntax for setting explicitly either the `soft` of the `hard` limits via `ulimit`?

Comment: The right syntax for setting requires reversing `-S` and `-n`: `root@Andromeda:/# ulimit -S -n 1024
root@Andromeda:/# ulimit -n -S 
1024
`

Comment: More properly: Per the utility conventions in the _Single Unix Specification_, and despite none of these options for `ulimit` being standardized, the correct syntax is for arguments to command-line options, the value of the limit in this case, to immediately follow the options themselves, such as `-n` in this case, without any other intervening command-line arguments.